# getting the current x, y position when adding contents to jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

i am trying to create pdf using jsPDF
is there any function which will return the current cursor position on writing contents to the pdf doc?

Answer (score 8):

The following code snippet shows a possible approach to derive the new y position after adding a line or block of text (you may test it on https://parall.ax/products/jspdf):

```
var doc = new jsPDF()
var text = 'This is a text without real content but with 59 characters.'

var lineHeight = doc.getLineHeight(text) / doc.internal.scaleFactor
var splittedText = doc.splitTextToSize(text, 50)
var lines = splittedText.length  // splitted text is a string array
var blockHeight = lines * lineHeight
var yPos = 10
var xPos = 10
doc.text(xPos, yPos, splittedText)
yPos += blockHeight
doc.text(xPos, yPos, '----- This text follows the previous text block.')
yPos += lineHeight
doc.text(xPos, yPos, '----- LineHeight=' + lineHeight + ' / blockHeight=' + blockHeight)
yPos += lineHeight
doc.text(xPos, yPos, '----- doc.internal.scaleFactor = ' + doc.internal.scaleFactor)
```

If you change the width defined as 2nd argument in the splitTextTosize() function (e.g. from 50 to 80), the y position of the next lines is adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same question and i search for a method or similar to get the current position. But i did not find one.

My solution is very simple. I have created local variables for x and y. I set them one time and after that i calculate the new position and save the value in the respective variable. So you know your current cursor position all the time.

Comment: Could you please share example ?

Comment: @Batajus how to do for tables that have dynamic height ?